# Overwriting style sheet for XML files view at browsers

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I wonder if it is possible to just overwrite the styles used by the browser to render an XML file. I would like to force it to load with the exactly same colors and font in all browsers.

Right now, I have downloaded and mofified the [DefaultSS.xsl](https://gist.github.com/alvarotrigo/8356036) file of IE<9 (which is suppose to be located in `res://msxml.dll/DEFAULTSS.xsl`) in order to use it as the template for my XML file.

I haven't been able to find any similar .xsl of modern versions of IE...

Combining this `.xls` file with the `.xml` [by using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13780386/1081396) I was able to style and format in my own way the XML, but I'm having some troubles with the XSL syntax and some problems have appeared. (such as showing the empty tags `<phone></phone>` instead of just `<phone />` without possibility to expand it)

That's why I was wondering if there isn't a more simple way to do it by just overwriting the CSS styles rather than having to use another `.xls` file as a template.

Comment: If you have control of the `.xml` file, you can add `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="url_to_the.xsl"?>` to the top of your `.xml` file. Or maybe http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html will help

Comment: I believe it doesn't work from local with Chrome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558160/xsl-not-working-in-google-chrome

Comment: Correct. Local XSL files will not be loaded by Chrome. I assume you want to view local XML content? :)

Comment: @andyb mmm not sure yet, but it's a possibility. How should anyway be the format of the .xls file to overwrite the styles? Where could I find an example?

Comment: Ah, you might actually want CSS here. XSLT is more about transformation of XML whereas I think you want styling - http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html should help

Comment: @andyb that would be a bit pain in the ass because different browsers creates a different HTML code for the representation with different classes as well. That's why I was using my own representation, to unify them.

Comment: @andyb do you know where can I find a modern .xsl template to render XML in the browser? The one I'm using is too old and commit some mistakes.

Comment: Sorry, no there is nothing I can find or think of other than fixing the IE one if you want to stick with XML/XSL. If you can use JavaScript, maybe Google's Prettify would suit your needs - https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Answer (score 0):

Use a user style sheet. Here is how to do it in IE:

- Create styles for XML using the wildcard (*) selector
- Save the stylesheet
- Go to the user style sheet menu

  - <kbd>Alt t</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
- Add the path to the stylesheet
- Test the XML file in question

For other browsers, the process is covered in other questions for [Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981707/1113772), [Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278020/1113772) and [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269982/1113772).

**References**

- [Use your own style sheet to format webpages](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Use-your-own-style-sheet-to-format-webpages?20dfb160)
- [Internet Explorer/Adding User Styles](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer/Adding_User_Styles)